# Hibernate FetchType.LAZY without session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, lazy-initialization

I have many issues with `LazyLoadingException` in a Spring web application wherever I try to access fields that are annotated with `FetchType.LAZY`

There is no session configured in Spring because the requirement is that the API should be stateless.

All the service layer methods have `@Transactional` annotations properly set. 
However when I try to access the Lazy fields on any domain object, I get the famous `LazyInitializationException (...) could not initialize proxy - no Session`

I thought that Hibernate would automatically load the lazy fields when needed when I'm in a `@Transactional` method but it appears it doesn't.

I have spent several days looking for answers but nothing fits my needs. I found that Spring could be configured with openSessionInViewFilter but it appears to cause many issues, moreover I don't have any session.

How to automatically load lazy fields in `@Transactional`annotated service methods with such a stateless API ?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm not very familiar with Spring and Hibernate.

Please tell me if there are missing information in my question I should give you.

Comment: You are mixing session and stateless however the session here is a hibernate session and not an http session and is as such not related to anything with being stateful or stateless.So yes you do have a session, you don't have an `HttpSession` but you have a `Session` from hibernate. 2 different things.

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification. So if an Hibernate session definitely exists, why isn't Hibernate using it to retrieve the lazy fields, but instead throws the LazyInitializationException ?

Comment: Because at that point, after the transaction, it doesn't exist anymore. It is bound to the transactional boundary, unless you are using an `OpenSessionInViewFilter`. Either use that or prepare your model correctly in the `@Transactional` annotated method.

Comment: _"I thought that Hibernate would automatically load the lazy fields when needed when I'm in a @Transactional method"_ Yes, it should load them automatically. It seems that you haven't integrated [Spring with Hibernate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html) well.

Comment: This is the point that I really don't get actually. I'm still in the @Transactionnal method when the exception occurs. I don't understand why there is no session at this point. Isn't the hibernate session supposed to stay open from the beggining of the method to it's end ?

Comment: Check weather you really are in a transactional method. Maybe you have two different beans of the same class and one of them is not advised with Spring transaction aspect.

Comment: If you get the exception your `@Transactional` is doing nothing, which means wrong setup. Or, what I see a lot, duplicate component scanning leading to 2 instances of beans 1 transactional, 1 non-transactional and the latter is being used.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic How to check if I'm really in a transactional method ?

Comment: @singe31 A simple way is by debugging your application. You'll then see the spring-created proxy as a part of the call stack.

Comment: @beerbajay In some stack traces I see `CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 649 
`, is it what you were refering to ?

Comment: @beerbajay Thanks to your recommendation (looking for the proxy in the stack trace) I noticed that some transactional services were calling some non-transactional utility methods which were accessing lazy fields but were not transactional, thus causing the lazy initialization exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LazyInitializationExceptions` are a code smell in a same way [EAGER fetching](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) is too.

First of all, the fetching policy should be query-based on a business case basis. Tha DAO layer is solely responsible for fetching the right associations, so:

1. You should use the `FETCH` directive for all `many-to-one` associations and at most one one-to-many association. If you try to JOIN FETCH more than one one-to-many associations, you'll get a Cartesian Product and your application performance will be affected.
2. If you need to fetch multiple collections, then a [multi-level fetching](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-multi-level-fetching/) is more appropriate.
3. You should ask yourself why you want to return entities from the DAO layer. Using DTOs is a much better alternative, as it reduces both the amount of data that's fetched from the DB and it doesn't leak the Entity abstraction into the UI layer.

Comment: That doesn't seem a very clean way to code. Using that I would need  to add a bunch a initialize everywhere in the service layer. It would make the code very hard to read and maintain in my opinion. Do you personnaly write such statements everywhere ?

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I don't think it will solve my issue but it will help make the application perform better when I'll manage to fix my issue. About DTOs , I'm using them but I don't see how they can reduce DB access since they're instantiated with a Builder pattern from a Domain Object. So when building the DTO, all the data is already fetch, right ? I didn't write that part of the application with DTO but it seems to me that there is a big problem there. How DTO are supposed to be populated by Hibernate ?

Comment: Hibernate supports the "select new package.DTO(id, name) from entity" syntax so you can fetch just as much data as you need. This can reduce query latency too.

Comment: Good, I didn't know about that. Does that mean that I have to write custom hql queries for every DTO ? Doesn't it exist some way to map DTO fields to Domain Object fields, this way Hibernate would automatically retrieve only the data that has existing fields in the DTO ?

Comment: Luckily, there's another option for that too. You can define multiple entities to the same database table: Employee, EmployeeFullName, EmployeeAddress. This way you can have a full-fetched entity and some sub-entities mapping to just a sub-set of the main database row.

Comment: Ok, if I'm understanding well, if I have a few domain objects for which I need different views it's better retrieving them with some DTO and the hql syntax, `select new package.DTO(id, name) from entity`. However if I need a lot of different views on several Domain Objects it's better to avoid DTO completely and have directly multiple variants of Domain Objects ? However, even in the first case (few different views needed).why bother with DTO if I can just have variants of Domain Objects. I don't really see the point of having DTO when I can just have variants of Domain Objects.

Comment: Using multiple versions of the same entity will move complexity from the DAO/Queries layer into the Entity/mapping one. With DTOs you always get a flat view over the query result-set, the Entity variants allow you to have some unidirectional associations, but you got to be careful not to tangle the domain model too much.

Comment: If you like this answer, you might consider accepting it too ;)

Comment: This is much clearer now, thank you. However it doesn't fix my "no session" issue so I can't mark it as the correct answer for now.

Comment: This explanation made me understand a lot better what was doing Hibernate while fetching Domain Objects. I noticed that some utility classes were accessing lazy fields without being transactional themselves, thus causing the lazy exception. Finally you answer contains good general best practices that I'll implement to improve the performances.